# Lua use case for my project

Tags: lua, scientific-computing

I have some basic requirements. In an windows PC I am supposed to

- Read some files.
- Perform some scientific computations on read file.
- Send and receive data to a board through peripherals.

Was searching for lightweight scripting language and stumbled upon Lua! Want to validate here, if Lua is a good choice? Questions are:

- Are there Lua libraries which can handle USB, Ethernet et.al. drivers ?
- Are there libraries available in Lua which can be used for scientific computation and/or data mining. In this case I will be needing linear algebra support, numerical analysis support and few more.

Please let me know your opinion if my choice is correct.

Comment: You used LUA, lua, and Lua in your question. It's Lua. Please correct the other mistakes. Also this is obviously opinion based, *Please let me know your opinion*, so it's OT for SO.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistakes. Indeed this is not a direct question. I am looking for qualitative replies - Indeed.

Answer (score 3):

**Lua** is very good for scientific computation because of **Torch** (http://torch.ch/). **The problem in your case would be the periphery support on Windows**. For Linux there is https://github.com/vsergeev/lua-periphery but I'm not sure if there is anything good for Windows out there.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I will try an internet search if I can find these.